# Rancher desktop unable to pull an image from Docker

Tags: containers, rancher, k3s, rancher-desktop, nerdctl

I have downloaded and set up Rancher Desktop with `nerdctl` but I am unable to pull any public image from the Docker Hub. I am receiving an error:

> INFO[0011] trying next host error="failed to do request: Head
> "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/maildev/maildev/manifests/latest":
> dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.47.23:53: read udp
> 192.168.47.23:37689->192.168.47.23:53: i/o timeout" host=registry-1.docker.io
>
> FATA[0011] failed to resolve reference
> "docker.io/maildev/maildev:latest": failed to do request: Head
> "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/maildev/maildev/manifests/latest":
> dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.47.23:53: read udp
> 192.168.47.23:37689->192.168.47.23:53: i/o timeout

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: Any luck ever solving this @HectorMartinez?

Comment: Did this get solved?